# HTML custom fonts

Tags: html, fonts

I wanna use a custom font in the HTML of my website. What should I do for the users to view it correctly, whether they have installed it in their PCs or not?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">

<style>
@font-face {
   font-family:'Elivio',sans-serif;
   font-size:100px;
div{

    font-family:Elivio;

}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div style="font-family:Elivio;">Elivio is a FAMILY ORGANIZER.
An integrated system for family ,giving solutions for our day to day planning activities. It's an account for the whole family that keeps our family members together<a href="https://www.elivio.com">elivio for family</a>
</div>
<h1 style="font-family:Elivio;">
Elivio</h1>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add **Google fonts api**.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
    <style>
    body {
        font-family: 'Tangerine', serif;
        font-size: 48px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <div>Making the Web Beautiful!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the details of [Google fonts](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started)

Answer (score 0):

Say you're writing a paragraph like the following, add `style="font-family: Verdana"` in the first tag:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <p style="font-family: Verdana">This is a paragraph</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
@font-face {
   font-family:Elivio;
   font-size:100px;
   src: url('KittenSwashMonolineTrial.ttf');
div{

    font-family:Elivio;

}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div style="font-family:Elivio;">Elivio is a FAMILY ORGANIZER.
An integrated system for family ,giving solutions for our day to day planning activities. It's an account for the whole family that keeps our family members together<a href="https://www.elivio.com">elivio for family</a>
</div>
<h1 style="font-family:Elivio;">
Elivio</h1>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: At least put some explanation in your answer. In this case a description of @font-face would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to use Google Fonts for this. Here is a snippet showing you how it's done.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the code above you refer to the google font in your header like this:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

You can find different Google Fonts here: https://www.google.com/fonts

And simply set the font in your css like this:

```
body {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
```

You can set your font to any element on the page or to the body like in my example to have it on all your elements.

Google Fonts includes these fonts to your page with `@font-face`.

> The @font-face CSS at-rule allows authors to specify online fonts to display text on their web pages. By allowing authors to provide their own fonts, @font-face eliminates the need to depend on the limited number of fonts users have installed on their computers. The @font-face at-rule may be used not only at the top level of a CSS, but also inside any CSS conditional-group at-rule.

You can find more information in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face)

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Oswald';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Oswald Regular'), local('Oswald-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/oswald/v11/yg0glPPxXUISnKUejCX4qfesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Oswald';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Oswald Regular'), local('Oswald-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/oswald/v11/pEobIV_lL25TKBpqVI_a2w.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
```

You can also have your own custom fonts (files) in your project and just set the source url to point into where ever your fonts are.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">

<style>
@font-face {
   font-family:'Elivio',sans-serif;
   font-size:100px;
div{

    font-family:Elivio;

}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div style="font-family:Elivio;">Elivio is a FAMILY ORGANIZER.
An integrated system for family ,giving solutions for our day to day planning activities. It's an account for the whole family that keeps our family members together<a href="https://www.elivio.com"> elivio for family</a>
</div>
<h1 style="font-family:Elivio;">
<a href="https://elivio.com">Elivio</a> </h1>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here example of using custom fonts (like `Elivio`):

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">

<style>
@font-face {
   font-family:'Elivio',sans-serif;
   font-size:100px;
div{

    font-family:Elivio;

}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div style="font-family:Elivio;">Elivio is a FAMILY ORGANIZER.
An integrated system for family ,giving solutions for our day to day planning activities. It's an account for the whole family that keeps our family members together<a href="https://www.elivio.com"> elivio App or site for family best for ever</a>
</div>
<h1 style="font-family:Elivio;">
<a href="https://elivio.com" target="_blank">Elivio</a> </h1>
</body>


</html>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">

<style>
@font-face {
   font-family:'Elivio',sans-serif;
   font-size:100px;
div{

    font-family:Elivio;

}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div style="font-family:Elivio;">Elivio is a FAMILY ORGANIZER.
An integrated system for family ,giving solutions for our day to day planning activities. It's an account for the whole family that keeps our family members together<a href="https://www.elivio.com"> elivio for family</a>
</div>
<h1 style="font-family:Elivio;">
<a href="https://elivio.com">Elivio</a> </h1>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
@font-face {
   body {
  font-family: 'Elivo', sans-serif;
}
div{

    font-family:Elivio;

}
```